# Cannot access raw resource when applicationId is built modified

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have modified my app so I can have both debug and production build on single mobile device as separate applications:

```
android { buildTypes { debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        resValue 'string', 'app_name', 'LeliMath DEV'
}
```

I realized that `WebView` stopped working on loading files located in `res/raw` folder. I get just simple error file not found. Production build works fine.

```
    WebView webview = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webview);
    webview.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/changelog.html");
```

Android monitor says:

```
AndroidProtocolHandler: Unable to open resource URL: file:///android_res/raw/changelog.html
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
Didn't find class "lelisoft.com.lelimath.debug.R$raw" on path: 
DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/lelisoft.com.lelimath.debug-1/base.apk"],
nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/lelisoft.com.lelimath.debug-1/lib/arm64, 
/system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]                                                                                       
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
```

Comment: I get the same when Proguard enabled and loading a .css file from `res/raw` that's a library project. If Proguard  is disabled in the implementing project that if works aok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try these steps:

1. Create new `R.java` file under different flavor directory. In your case create this file inside this package `lelisoft.com.lelimath.debug` inside your `debug` flavor directory.
2. Duplicate your normal `R.java` content or just pick what do you need and set it with the value from your normal `R.java`.
   For example:

```java
package lelisoft.com.lelimath.debug;
public final class R {
   public static final class raw {
      public static final String changelog = lelisoft.com.lelimath.R.raw.changelog;
   }
}
```

3. Last, add this line to your proguard:

`-keep class lelisoft.com.lelimath.debug.R$raw {*;}`

You could repeat those steps to any flavor you have. Hope it fix your problem.